# How to show and hide sliding elements in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show an element by sliding it up in the screen with css bottom:0

and then I need to drag it down to simply dismiss it (hide it by changing its css bottom:-100% property).

This is my current code:

```js
let scrollingTimeout;
const scrollableElement = $('.popup');
var isItsCROLLING;

var isDragging = false;
var startY;
var draggableModals = $('.popup');
var threshold = 200; // Adjust the threshold for sliding down



const startDrag = (e) => {
  isDragging = true;
  startY = e.originalEvent.touches ? e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY : e.clientY;
};

const doDrag = (e) => {
    

  if (isDragging) {

    const clientY = e.originalEvent.touches ? e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY : e.clientY;
    
    const deltaY = clientY - startY;

    draggableModals.each(function () {
      const newTop = $(this).offset().top + deltaY;
 // Move each modal vertically only if it's not going beyond the bottom of the page
      if (newTop >= $(window).height() - $(this).outerHeight()) {
        $(this).css('top', newTop + 'px');
      }
      // Move each modal vertically
      //$(this).css('top', newTop + 'px');
    });

    // Update the start position for the next move
    startY = clientY;
  }
};

const stopDrag = () => {
  isDragging = false;
 
  draggableModals.each(function () {
      console.log($(this).offset().top);
    // Check if each modal is dragged beyond the threshold
    if ($(this).offset().top > threshold) {
       
      // If dragged beyond the threshold, slide down to hide
      $(this).css({
        transition: 'bottom 0.3s ease-in-out',
        top: '',
      });

    

      // Reset transition after animation completes
      setTimeout(() => {
        $(this).css('transition', '');
      }, 400);
    }
  });
};

draggableModals.on('mousedown touchstart', startDrag);
$(document).on('mousemove touchmove', doDrag);
$(document).on('mouseup touchend', stopDrag);






$(document).on('click', 'button', function(){ 

$('.popup').css('bottom', 0)

   
});
```

```css
.popup{
  width:100%;
  height:80%;
  background: blue;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:-100%;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
click here
</button>


<div class="popup">

drag me down to dismis me

</div>
```

but I cannot dismiss the element by dragging it down.

how can I achieve this?